# Error: can't evaluate field IsView in type drivers.Table

Tags: postgresql, psql, sqlboiler

**Environment:**

- SQLBoiler Version: v3.7.1

**Issue Description:**

I'm encountering an issue while running SQLBoiler with PostgreSQL. The error message is:

```
$ sqlboiler psql
Error: singleton template output: failed to execute template: test/singleton/psql_suites_test.go.tpl: template: test/singleton/psql_suites_test.go.tpl:3:37: executing "test/singleton/psql_suites_test.go.tpl" at <$table.IsView>: can't evaluate field IsView in type drivers.Table
```

**sqlboiler.toml file:**

```ini
output = "models/sqlboiler"
pkgName = "sqlboiler"
wipe = false
no-tests = true
add-enum-types = true

[psql]
dbname = "test"
host = "localhost"
port = 5432
user = "api"
pass = "password"
sslmode = "disable"
```

I am trying to generate SQLBoiler models, and I am running PostgreSQL in a Docker container. The expectation is that models for all tables should be generated.

This way, the code and configuration details are properly formatted for better readability, and it should resolve the error you're encountering when posting.